# Must I create a bootable USB drive on the computer I intend to use it on?

Tags: iso

Or is a universal thing?
I'd like to create the bootable USB drive on a computer where the connection is much faster that the computer I plan on using Ubuntu on.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't matter on what computer you create the bootstick on. The stick can then be booted from basically any computer with support for the installed architecture.

Example: If you download the 64bit ISO for a 64bit computer, on a 32bit computer, you can create the bootstick from on this 32bit machine. However, you can't boot Ubuntu on this machine, since it doesn't understand 64bit instructions. If you now plug the stick into the 64bit computer, you can boot Ubuntu from there.

Think of the bootstick as a DVD: You can burn a DVD on one computer and boot Ubuntu from it on another one. The bootstick is nearly the same.

---

My preference: Use [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) for creating the bootstick. It's the best-working tool I know and is available for Windows, Linux and Mac OS X.

Comment: As this answers your question, please mark it as accepted so it is removed from the Unanswered list.